# cakephp 1.3 datasource change issue

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am using CakePHP 1.3 with two data sources:

1. `master`
2. `default`

How can I change the data source for a whole function i.e. from `default` to `master` for that function.

If I use this

```
$this->{Model}->setDataSource('master');
```

it only changes for that model.

Is there any general way???

Comment: in which cases you need to use master and where default ?

Comment: function which uses any single save/update operation ...i want to use master data source for that functionality( for complete function)..

Comment: So in one session you will need to use both datasources ?Based on which function called ?

Comment: suppose i call one controller/action ..it should be like that we can change datasource in starting of function ..and it should use that datasource till end of that function...

Answer (score 4):

OK. Try doing something like this. I tried it in newer version of cake and its worked.

in your app model have a function

```
public function getDataSource(){
    $dataSource = Configure::read('currentDataSource');
    if($dataSource && $dataSource !== $this->useDbConfig){
        $this->setDataSource($dataSource);
    }
    return parent::getDataSource();
}
```

Then in your controller , based which data source needed write it in configure.

```
Configure::write('currentDataSource', 'yourDbsource');
```

Then call to any of your models.

Dont forget to specify default one from bootstrap.php.

Comment: actually in cakephp 1.3 there is no function called getDataSource..so we cant override....i checked in library...

Comment: Actually here is it http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/class-Model.html#_getDataSource Maybe problem is somewhere in other point, is it giving error or just not working as expected ?

Comment: From my own experimentation, it seems you need to call getDataSource immediately after changing the configuration.